# TCP traceroute to specific port?

Tags: networking, debug, traceroute

Is it possible to use tcptraceroute to probe a certain port? The documentation in the man pages seems to suggest that the '-p' port flag is for UDP, and when used with tcptraceroute, is for specifying the source port?

How do I specify the destination port? (eg. 443, or 500)

Thanks

Comment: Is `man traceroute ; traceroute -T -p 443 www.example.com` not working for you?

Comment: That works, but shouldn't I see <syn,ack> at the final hop?

Comment: If that's your question, I suggest *actually asking that question*.  I *do* see syn-ack, but we can't start discussing the evidence for that in response to the question as written.